# How to write recommendation documentation?

Tags: requirements, documentation, change-management, specification

I was asked to prepare an overview of an existing IT architechture and provide a document that consists of weaknesses analysis and suggestions on how each of the weak spots can be improved.

How to make this document simple to read, not overloaded and specific at the same time? Is there a template I can use for this kind of documentation?

Also, should I provide a description of how a specific segment in the system currently works before I put explanation about what should be changed?

Thank you

Comment: Seems a bit off-topic here. You might want to consider https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing

Answer (score 1):

1. This depends on what the target audience is for your propositions. More details to more technically-oriented people, less details for the people who controls budgeting.
2. Architecture is always a high-level thing. So if you analyse the weaknesses on architectural level there is no need to get into details.
3. You should rather concentrate on the value of the changes you propose. What risks are covered, what are the costs, what might happen if the thing will remain as is.
4. Use info-graphics approach
5. Provide the summary page at the end